# Web components custom elements form element submitting

Tags: javascript, form-submit, custom-element

I working on a form made just out of custom elements. The form should be submitted when I click on the button. I have some problems with communication between custom elements. When I click on the button it calls the form submit, but the onsubmit function doesnt get called, the alert doesent appear. Can you help me with that?

```
    <form-element action="" method="POST">
        <textfield-element name="number" validation="[0-9]+"> </textfield-element>
        <textfield-element name="subject"> </textfield-element> 
        <button-element> Send </button-element>
 element</button> -->
    </form-element>
```

```
class ButtonElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.onclick = () => {
            const form = this.closest('form');
            form.submit();
        }
    }
}

window.customElements.define('button-element', ButtonElement)
```

```
class FormElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.formNode = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('form')

        for (let i = 0; i < this.childNodes.length; i++) {
            if(this.childNodes[i].localName === 'textfield-element' || this.childNodes[i].localName === 'button-element'){
                this.formNode.appendChild(this.childNodes[i])
            }
        }
        this.onsubmit = () => {
            alert('hey')
        }

    }
}

window.customElements.define('form-element', FormElement)
```

Comment: For one, your button says `const form = this.closest('form');`, but your form-element is not a `form`, it's a `form-element`. Having said that, why are you redeclaring things that already exist? Forms and text inputs and buttons already have perfectly fine HTML elements defined?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find a `<form>` within the shadow DOM of `<form-element>` with
`this.closest('form');`? You'd have to do something like `this.closest('form-element').shadowDOM.querySelector('form')` to do that.
Other than that your solution of calling `submit()` on the form should work. I don't like this solution though, because when submitted programmatically the form doesn't emit a `SubmitEvent`. As a dev using your components I would expect the form to emit that event. I think it's a pretty serious limitation not to use it, and potentially hard to figure out.

Querying the form to call `submit()` on it is one of 3 solutions I'm aware of.
The most obvious one is to use a `<button type="submit">` inside your `<button-element>`, but you can't use shadow DOM, which would block the click event from reaching the form. The other solution I've seen is pretty hacky: when `<button-element>` is clicked, create a button outside of the shadow DOM, programmatically click it and remove it.